# How to stop multiple of 13 appearing in an Identity Column

Tags: sql

Say I have the following table:

```
Create Table Comments (
    ID Int Identity(1,1) Not Null Primary Key Clustered,
    Comment Text Not Null
)
```

Since I'm superstitious, how can I stop multiples of 13 appearing in the ID column?
ie: Skip 13, 26, 39 etc.

Solution in MySQL or MSSQL much appreciated.

Comment: Aww man. This may be an extreme example of a meta-problem, but it is an interesting question. Maybe he is using the identity as a customer number for a gambling site and his customers are superstitious.

Re-open it!

Comment: +1 re-open.  Why close it?  The rationale may be peculiar but it is a perfectly valid technical programming question.  If you close this you have to spend the next 12 hours closing every other question whose rationale you don't think is good enough.

Comment: I think it's a rather goofy question myself. Though I'm interested to see an answer.  While I won't vote up the question, I'll vote to reopen it.

Comment: To be fair, it's possible that only one person voted "not a real question" and we're just seeing that reason.

Comment: You should read the question before voting to close.

Comment: +1 to reopen. Ignore that "superstitious" part; how can you avoid certain numbers in sequences is a valid question.

Comment: @Aaron, not only did you say what I was going to say, you used the words I was going to use.

Comment: I agree with keeping it open.  The only reason I could think of to suggest closing it, is that it sounds a bit like a homework question.

Comment: Probably not from someone with 6K points :)

Comment: This is absurd. Since when is 26 an unlucky number? Avoiding certain numbers in a sequence is a fine question, but in a SQL identity column? No. I doubt anyone looks at 156 (13*12) and thinks oh noes1!!!

Comment: Guys, enjoy the absurd! :) Life is too short to answer only serious questions. And you'll never know when this might come handy!

Comment: Agreed with JCollum: There's only one number that this would really apply to.  I agree that the question is silly.

Comment: It is an honest no-homework question. I'm working on a community website and I don't want anyone's user ID to include unlucky numbers. Also, the answers so far are very good :)

Comment: In what religion is anything other than 13/666 an unlucky number? (nevermind that 666 isn't divisible by 13).

Comment: Gortok, you right :) I will be blocking other numbers apart from multiples of 13. I just didn't mention it to keep the question short.

Comment: Gotcha. Though unless we know what numbers you want to block, there's no automatic method (other than a trigger to block those numbers, or function that creates Primary Keys with a blacklist of keys to not allow) to do this.

Comment: Are there any other numerologies that we should be aware of? Would 555 or 777 get special treatment, like a halo (christian numerology)? What about the Kaballah? Do we need to keep Indian mysticism in mind? lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a trigger to skip to the next one every time 13n - 1 comes up in the sequence

BradC, this is for you.  Without any knowledge of SQL Server, I'll do it in Oracle.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) seems to be a good reference for triggers in SQL Server

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigname 
  AFTER INSERT ON Comments
  FOR EACH ROW 
  IF (:new.ID % 13 = 12) THEN
    -- increase the sequence
    SELECT comment_ID_sequence.NEXTVAL FROM dual;
  END IF;   
END;
```

Without actually testing it, this will probably not work, but with a small amount of trial and error, you can get it working.  Oracle has sequence objects that aren't tied to the table at all, and you can bump the sequence all day if you want, without ever touching the table.  I don't know if this is true in SQL Server.

Comment: What, an insert trigger? Care to give some details on what that would look like?

Comment: So ... a 13 in a trigger is ok?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: previous answer was completely wrong.

You can do it like this:

```
Identity(1, 13)
```

As tested by:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i += 13)
{
    if (i % 13 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Incrementing by 13, starting from 1 should never give you a multiple of 13, at least up to the 10 million.

Comment: My previous answer was wrong/misleading, so I did some tests, and realized the answer is as simple as starting from 1 and incrementing by 13.

Comment: Doesn't that leave a lot of empty IDs?

Comment: Of course, and the IDs will get pretty big, relatively quickly. It's a pretty simple solution, however.

Comment: @devinb: why would it matter if you have a lot of empty ids?

Comment: Maybe because the precious space between 1 and 14 is being wasted so flippantly?

Comment: I like my answer, but this one is just so much more devious.

Answer (score 3):

Identity(7919, 4966)

This returned 432'436 unique IDs within a 32bit int and none was a multiple of 13.

More pairs:

17, 1040 - Yields 2'064'889 values

17, 559 - Yields 3'841'653 values

[EDIT] Small python program to test:

```
import sys

def x(start, step):
    count = 0
    i = start
    N = 1 << 31
    while i < N:
        #print i
        if i % 13 == 0:
            break
        i += step
        count += 1
    print i, i/13.0, count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

I just used a couple of primes but that didn't really work; with primes, I could only get sequences with 1-12 numbers. So I started with a random pair and varied the second number until the script would stop to return.

I have no idea of the mathematical properties of the two numbers ;) Anyone?

Comment: This is very interesting...can you describe how you came up with those numbers?  I'm thinking some neat math.

Comment: Err... I started with the primes < 10000 and then wrote a small python program to verify which ones were OK ;) I'm more coder and less math genius ...

Answer (score 2):

Create a trigger on insert.

When inserting something which is a multiple of 13 minus 1 (12, 25, 38, etc.) insert and delete another row immediately.

Something like that (might need modifications):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ON [table_name]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    -- Get the last inserted identifier
    DECLARE @LastID INT -- or whatever type is your identity column
    SET @LastID = SELECT ID FROM inserted -- inserted holds the inserted entry

    -- Check if the ID is a multiple of thirteen minus 1
    IF ((@LastID + 1) % 13 = 0) -- not sure it would work, but something like that
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [table_name]
        -- dummy values

        DELETE FROM [table_name] WHERE ID = (@LastID + 1)
    END

GO
```

Comment: I'm not well versed in triggers, but wouldn't that create a race condition?

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, and is probably the best answer.

Comment: @saua: no it would not create a race condition  the table is locked until the trigger is done.

Comment: why couldn't this be done BEFORE INSERT so you could modify the id before it gets committed?

Comment: Well, if he is superstitious, he won't like the 13 in your trigger as well ;)

Comment: it could, but you would have to use similar logic either way

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table Comments (    
    ID Int Identity(2,2) Not Null Primary Key Clustered,    
    Comment Text Not Null
)
```

Comment: Tony seems to be on to something.  Perhaps we go Identity(1,26) to avoid any hint of 13.